# How to get actual disk size from libvirt-python (3 questions!)

Tags: python, storage, libvirt

I've been working with virt-manager and am now moving into some custom code using python and libvirt.

I have noticed that some of my VMs show "unknown" in regard to the disk "Storage size".

Using virsh gives me what *roughly* appear to be correct results:

```
virsh # domblkinfo 10 vda
Capacity:       32212254720
Allocation:     31936634880
Physical:       31935758336
```

... "Capacity" I assume is the maximum of the defined drive. However in this case, the actual defined size, (using qemu-img) the *guest OS* sees as 25GB (total) - which is what was requested.

virsh domblkinfo shows 30G (if those numbers are bytes)

The *host OS* says the current qcow2 file size is 17GB. (which makes sense as it is a COW disk).

However...

- I can't seem to find a way to do this using libvirt-python. Has anyone done this?
- The documentation seems to be a bit murky as to what those numbers actually mean - suggesting that they are block size. Seem to be bytes to me.
- Where did the extra 5Gb come from?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short, you should first extract info about disks path from domain XML, and the pass it to `blockInfo()` method, so the full script will look like the following:

```
import libvirt
from xml.dom import minidom

conn = libvirt.open('qemu:///system')
domainIDs = conn.listAllDomains(0)

print("\tNAME\tSTATE\tCPUs\tMEM\tDISK\tUSED")
for domain in domainIDs:
        raw_xml = domain.XMLDesc(0)
        state, maxmem, mem2, cpus, cput = domain.info()
        name = domain.name()
        mem   = domain.maxMemory()/1024**2
        xml = minidom.parseString(raw_xml)
        diskTypes = xml.getElementsByTagName('disk')
        for diskType in diskTypes:
                if diskType.getAttribute('device') == 'disk':
                        diskNodes = diskType.childNodes
                        for diskNode in diskNodes:
                                if diskNode.nodeName == 'source':
                                        for attr in diskNode.attributes.keys():
                                                if diskNode.attributes[attr].name == 'file':
                                                        blkinf = domain.blockInfo(diskNode.attributes[attr].value)
                if   state == 1: vmstate = "running"
                elif state == 5: vmstate = "stopped"
                disksize = round(blkinf[0]/1024**3)
                diskused = round(blkinf[1]/1024**3)
        print(name+"\t"+vmstate+"\t"+str(cpus)+"\t"+str(mem)+"G"+"\t"+str(disksize)+"G\t"+str(diskused)+"G")

conn.close()
```

the result should be like following:

```
        NAME    STATE   CPUs    MEM     DISK    USED
cos6-copy       stopped 2       1.0G    64G     2G
centos6.i386    running 2       1.0G    64G     2G
```

Comment: It returns the first disk only, but it should be easy enough to get it to iterate through all found. Thanks!